# Is char p[0] represents an auto allocated buffer or a safe pointer?

Tags: c++, c

This is C++ code which shows a compiler warning but runs fine. The expected behavior was as below, but:

```
char sz[] = "Hello World";
char *p;
snprintf(p, 12, sz);
printf("%s", p);
```

The above code when ran, it crashes as the *p is not allocated. Good.

```
char sz[] = "Hello World";
char p[0];
snprintf(p, 12, sz);
printf("%s", p);
```

The above code works fine and will display "Hello World" without any errors.
While compiling the above show a compiler warning it is illegal to use [0], but runs fine.

Why it is so?

Comment: First of all, please pick *one* language, C and C++ are two very different languages, especially when it come to semantics like this. Other than that, welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you have UB (Undefined Behavior) then all discussion about behavior becomes moot.

Comment: dumb bad luck. [Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) has, well, behaviour that's undefined. It could do anything, and that includes look like it works.

Comment: "Runs fine" is a bit optimistic... You are probably overwriting unrelated portions of the stack. Still, it's interesting that in your implementation `p` decays to a pointer to some portion of memory that is decent enough to be overwritten (albeit illegally). Given that all this code falls straightly into undefined behavior and implementation-defined behavior territory, you should specify what compiler you are using.

Comment: A good behavior is also a sub-set of un-defined behavior. These kind of code is not recommended. you indeed know here the you are writing to an un-allocated memory. And also compiler is warning you, this is what we can call as assistance from compiler. Whenever you compile a code it should be 0-error and 0-warning, just follow this rule and you will witness very less un-defined behavior. :)

Comment: The dupe link is useful information, but it is not a duplicate, because it fails to clarify (or at least call) the misunderstanding of auto-allocation and the question why it "works" for second code.

Comment: Thank you all. This issue came across when I was reviewing someone code. The problem is nowadays most of the C++ coding is written by C developers. This is first time I was seeing an array of zero size and want to know why the programmer meant by such a code.

Answer (score 5):

> Why it is so?

It is still undefined behavior.

It works in your setup because, by coincidence, the array that holds `"Hello World"` is adjacent to the variable `p` in the stack.

Don't rely on such code and don't use them. The behavior of such code can change with compiler changes, using different compiler options, etc.

Comment: Not very sure it is because of adjacent memory location, as p is defined after sz and it works fine  everytime.

Comment: @Krishna, unfortunately, even seemingly sane behavior is under undefined behavior. All I can say is don't rely on such code.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
char p[0];
```

is defining an array of chars of length 0, at a position decided by the linker.
There is no space to print anything into it.

The only difference/improvement compared to

```
char *p;
```

Is that the latter does not even have the linker decide on where to put the zero sized space.

You need space to print into. Neither of the two methods provides/reserves any.

Change to

```
char p[<N>];
```

with `<N>` being a suitably high number to ensure sufficient space, if you can decide on one before compiling.

Use

```
char* p;
/* ... */
p = malloc(<N>);
```

if you do not know the suitable size before runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet, as you expected, invokes undefined behavior by accessing uninitialized pointer (*invalid memoory*). Good.

The second snippet, is a **constraint violation**. For an array declaration like `p[0]`, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.2, (*emphasis mine*)

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit
>   an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
>   expression shall have an integer type. **If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero.** [....]

So, the code is not *valid*, your compiler should not have produced a binary out of that code. Pump up your compiler warnings.

Comment: "*Good*"? Really? No. ;-)

Comment: @alk I meant good in context of "as expected" . :)

Comment: Just noticed this. Yes, I did it again. I did not completely read the question. Shame on me ...

Comment: @alk :) I hope you get the meaning now. I'm wondering in that case, whether my answer would be _unwelcoming_? :P

Comment: Hu, yesnowell ... annotate it with a wink and your good.

Answer (score 1):

```
char sz[] = "Hello World";
char *p;
snprintf(p, 12, sz);
printf("%s", p);
```

correct will get error memory not allocate

```
char sz[] = "Hello World";
char p[0];
snprintf(p, 12, sz);
printf("%s", p);
```

some of the compiler allocate size as per string length but mostly we should avoid this and this is compiler dependent issue nothing related to `snprintf`

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me. I could guess, but I won't.

Comment: @alk The above code works fine and will display "Hello World" without any errors. While compiling the above show a compiler warning it is illegal to use [0], but runs fine.
Why it is so? that's what tring to explain some of the compiler will allocate memory as per required length to variable and store data/string into that, pop a warning message  :)